# installing webMIDIKit for xcode project

Tags: swift, midi, package-managers

I am trying to add webMIDIKit to a swift project in xcode and I just can't figure out how.

[Here is the github page:](https://github.com/adamnemecek/WebMIDIKit/)

I have no idea what the install directions are trying to tell me

**Installation**

Use Swift Package Manager.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "WebMIDIKitDemo",
    dependencies: [
      .Package(url: "https://github.com/adamnemecek/WebMIDIKit.git", majorVersion: 1)
    ]

)
```

I have tried typing this into terminal but I just get errors.  Could someone explain to me how to add WebMIDIKit to my project.  Please keep it simple as I am a beginner.  Thanks.

Comment: This will show you how use SPM with your project. [How to setup SPM](https://swift.org/package-manager/)  ***Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms.***

Comment: thanks MwcsMac, but I had already found that site and found it confusing.  I don't want to create a package, I just want to install one into my project.

Comment: I managed to get the WebMIDIKitDemo project to load and compile.  It uses WebMIDIKit, so I believe I have everything I need, I just need to figure out how to add WebMIDIKit to my app.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The best way is to copy all of the files from the `Sources/WebMIDIKit` folder into your project.

Answer (score 0):

How the readme tells, you need to use [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/)

And here's [the complete guide](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager)

[image]